# Minimum number of samples to reach 95% confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval

I have reached this type of problem quite a lot of times, but this problem still bugs me. I got it wrong, and I am still not sure how to do it.

The question is following:

You gave out a lecture to a student, and you decide to test whether the student really 'understood' the lecture.

```
P(getting the question correct | understood the lecture) = 1/2
P(getting the question correct | did not understand the lecture) = 1/4
```

then what's the minimum number of questions you have to ask the student to reach at least 95% confidence level about whether the student really understood the lecture or not.

The hint says the answer would be between 4 and 8 (inclusive), but I keep getting the answer greater than that.

Comment: Could you please explain *how* you are obtaining an answer?  The guidance found at [tag:self-study] will help you improve the formulation of this question.